# Why does $(document).ready(function()... not work in this example?

Tags: jquery

Why does **$(document).ready(function()** not work in the following example?

If I take it out, the other jQuery statement works.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Text Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("p").css("background-color","green");
            });

            function highlightIt() {
                $("p").css("background-color","yellow");
            }
        </script>       


    </head>

<body>

    <p>this is a test</p>

    <form action="">
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="highlight it" onclick="highlightIt()" />
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Google Load you have to use:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Do something
    });
});
```